# How can I loop this Python program indefinitely, and convert floating point hours into hours and minutes?

Tags: python, loops, time, calculator

So i need to make a fuel consumption calculator that will also count time spent on a specific trip.

**I cant figure out how to make the program tell me the time spent in "hours:minutes" format rather than just a floating point variable for hours.**

`Time traveled: 1.6666666666666667 hours`
should be
`Time traveled: 1h:45min`

**Additionally, I'm not sure how to make the program repeat the questions and give results infinitely until shut down.**

This is the code i have:

```
# Get L/100km used from the user
fuel = input("Enter car's L/100kmh:")
fuel = float(fuel)

# Get distance driven from the user
distance = input("Enter kilometers driven:")
distance = float(distance)

# Get speed used from the user
speed = input("Enter driving speed:")
speed = float(speed)

# Calculate and print the answer
time = distance / speed
fuel_burned = distance / 100 * fuel
print("Time traveled:", time,"hours")
print("Fuel burned:", fuel_burned,"liters")
```

Comment: Your questions have nothing to do with a GUI. Do you want a GUI that can cope with your requirements?

Comment: A GUI is a graphical user interface, meaning working with things other than text.  I am thinking you want a CLI, or command-line interface, which will loop over and over, asking user for input, which they type in and hit enter, until they are ready to quit, when they will enter something else to quit.  Is this a better representation of what you want?

Comment: You are correct - CLI, command-line type of thing is what i have in mind...
The Title ended up there by mistake and now i cant change it - i wasn't even supposed to mention GUI here...

Comment: roganjosh, do you perhaps have an idea for how to turn this into a GUI? cause that would be even better...

Comment: How would you do it with pen and paper? Figure that out first. Then try to code it up.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This code has been edited considerably to be as accurate as possible. My solution assumes that you want to be able to exit the program gracefully, rather than having it terminate at system shutdown, but if that is not the case, simply remove the final portion of the loop, starting at `again = ...`.

```
while True:
    # Get L/100km used from the user
    fuel = input("Enter car's L/100kmh:")
    fuel = float(fuel)

    # Get distance driven from the user
    distance = input("Enter kilometers driven:")
    distance = float(distance)

    # Get speed used from the user
    speed = input("Enter driving speed:")
    speed = float(speed)

    # Calculate and print the answer
    time = distance / speed
    fuel_burned = distance / 100 * fuel
    hours = int(time)
    minutes_remainder = (time - hours) * 60
    minutes = int(minutes_remainder) 
    print("Time traveled: ", hours,":",minutes)
    print("Fuel burned: ", fuel_burned," liters")

     again = input("Go again? (y/n)")
     if again == "n":
        break
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903846/c-convert-decimal-hours-into-hours-minutes-and-seconds) is an example of converting decimal hours to hours:mins:seconds in C++, which I used to arrive at the solution I have given.

Comment: It's Python... and tagged as such.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap it in a while loop. Your title makes no sense though as this has nothing to do with a GUI (Graphical User Interface)

## Example:

```
while True: 

    # Get L/100km used from the user
    fuel = input("Enter car's L/100kmh:")
    fuel = float(fuel)

    # Get distance driven from the user
    distance = input("Enter kilometers driven:")
    distance = float(distance)

    # Get speed used from the user
    speed = input("Enter driving speed:")
    speed = float(speed)

    # Calculate and print the answer
    time = distance / speed
    fuel_burned = distance / 100 * fuel
    print("Time traveled:", time,"hours")
    print("Fuel burned:", fuel_burned,"liters")
```